# Obtaining analytics data by using REST API calls on IBM API Connect Developer portal

Tags: websphere, analytics, portal, ibm-api-connect

I am looking for a way to fetch API Connect analytics data i.e. a number of requests of APIs exposed via API Connect, by which client, etc. I know, there is an individual dashboard/chart within API Connect. But, I want to build an explicit tool to monitor the same leveraging API Connect data on the IBM API Connect Developer portal. If anyone has the answer please reply to me.

With reference to the https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/api-connect/5.0.x?topic=veaaed-obtaining-analytics-data-by-using-rest-api-calls I have tried but my question is how without any authentication we get the data and if authentication requires then how can we call the API and fetch the data.

Answer (score 0):

According to the doc, HTTP basic auth is required.  Your post doesn't specify how you want to retrieve the data, but as an example from the command line using curl

```
curl -k -X GET -u 'username@company.com' -p 'somePassword' 'https://api-manager-server.company.com/v1/orgs/macs-shack/
environments/sb/events?after=2016-08-01T00:00:00.000&before=2016-09-30T23:59:59.999'
```